# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The handle is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sendmail

I am getting exception while sending mail through C# for

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()
```

as **System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The handle is invalid.**

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from,to);

            mail.To.Add(to);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from, "", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            mail.Subject = "This is a test mail";

            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            mail.Body = fr.message;

            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

            //Add the Creddentials- use your own email id and password
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, Password);

            client.Port = 587; // Gmail works on this port

            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

            client.EnableSsl = true; //Gmail works on Server Secured Layer

                client.Send(mail);
```

I am not getting why this happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [new MailMessage() Throws 'The handle is invalid'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610424/new-mailmessage-throws-the-handle-is-invalid)

Comment: isn't the port `465` for ssl ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question had the exception on the `MailMessage` constructor, but here it happens on the `SmtpClient` constructor. Also, the other question has no real answer.

Comment: Try wrapping your MailMessage and SmtpClient in `using` blocks: `using (var mail = new MailMessage(...)){ ... using (var client = new SmtpClient(...)){ ...}}`

Comment: This code works well on my machine. What platform do you use?

Comment: i found a solution in another threat. Please check 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504760/sitecore-system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Is it the line that sets the Crendentials? If so I guess the problem is related to the Password property. Also, please show your config. The empty ctor uses the mailSettings config element.

Answer (score 1):

Check your project settings and make sure you have checked NTLM Authentication:

[image]