# CryptographicException is thrown on new MailMessage()

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code in an ASP.NET site

```
using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
{
    ...
}
```

throws System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The handle is invalid. exception.

The SMTP setting in my web.config file is:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="myaccount@gmail.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" port="587" userName="myaccount@gmail.com" password="mypass" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

This was working yesterday. The exception started to thrown today - after I upgraded to VS 2012.

Anyone has seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As found in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610424/new-mailmessage-throws-the-handle-is-invalid)

What I did to 'fix' is just to restart my computer and everything starts to working again.